# Dual space of space of all smooth function

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, locally-convex-spaces

On the space $C^\infty(S^1,\mathbb R)$, for each $n\in \mathbb N$, define 
$$p_N(\gamma)= \max\{|f^{(k)}(t): t\in S^1, k\leq N\}$$

Topology of all norms above define a metrizable locally convex topology (in fact Frechet space) on this space [Rudin Functional analysis page 35].

> How to calculate dual space to this space,

For dual space, I mean set of all continuous linear functional on $C^\infty(S^1, M)$ with norms
$$p'_M(f)= \sup_{\gamma\in M\subset C^\infty(S^1,\mathbb R)}|f(\gamma)|$$ and $M$ runs through all bounded subsets of $L$.

My background and others:  I do not have enough practice and knowledge of functional analysis course.. Hence i will be happy if i get reference reading for this so that i can calculate dual myself.

> What are the books/topic name which i should read to get comfortable
>   in calculating these type questions

Comment: I get the impression that the completion of this space is $H^N$. If this is true, the dual is the dual of $H^N$, which is $H^N$ or $H^{-N}$ depending on how you identify it (if I remember right).

Comment: Also how did this question come up? I think that would give at least some direction responders can proceed in.

Comment: @user45150 thanks for the comment, but space is complete.. I edited the question, i guess you confused that i am fixing $N$.. but topology is coming from all these countable seminorms.

Comment: This is the space of all distributions on the circle if I'm correct.

Comment: @Ahriman,  How did you get that.. can you please explain or give some reference..

Comment: How do you define distributions on a compact manifold ?

Comment: @Ahriman,  Thanks.. Now i think, roughly i got.. i need to study distribution and then compare that with same strong topology on dual, distribution space may be required space..... but in the mean time, perhaps, some more comment/answer may come and which will help me..

Comment: You can consult this book in the part of distributions (there he show how to define a distribution in a Manifold and he proves what @Ahriman said): http://books.google.com.br/books/about/Partial_Differential_Equations.html?id=vISPd8QJfHoC&redir_esc=y

Answer (score 1):

For a compact space, this is indeed the space of all distributions, which has the topology of pointwise convergence. To check that something is a continuous functional, you can check continuity with respect to the seminorms in $C^{\infty}(M)$ separately (this construction can be generalised to smooth sections of vector bundles where you have connections).

The second norm that you write gives the strong topology or the topology of uniform convergence on bounded subsets. In general they are not the same, though they coincide for Banach spaces. 
When $M$ is not compact, the topology on $C_c(M)$ is more complicated (for example, see Richard Melrose's notes on Differential Analysis pp. 40). A general good reference is Michael E. Taylor's Partial Differential Equations, Vol I, appendix A, which has an excellent condensed account of the functional analytic tools that are normally used.